# Как узнать ключ элемента в многомерном массиве?

Tags: php, массивы, key

Есть многомерный массив, который надо изменить в соответсвии с ключом, но никак не могу сделать так чтобы выводился ключ вот массив:

```
    Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => 52 [1] => #FF00FF [2] => XL [3] => 26 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [discount-size] => 50 )
     [1] => Array ( [0] => 52 [1] => #FF00FF [2] => S [3] => 25 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [discount-size] => 50 )
     [2] => Array ( [0] => 52 [1] => #A0522D [2] => XL [3] => 24 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [discount-size] => 50 )
     [3] => Array ( [0] => 52 [1] => #A0522D [2] => S [3] => 23 [4] => 0 [5] => 0 [discount-size] => 50 )
 )
```

Вот функция вывода:

```
foreach ( $array as $movie ) {
echo $movie[1];
echo movie[2];
т.д
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $movie ) {
echo $key;
}
```